# Pass data and a variable to a template

Tags: go, go-templates

I have a page where I get a variable from URL and use it to fetch some data from a database. I then pass the data to the template and display the results.
What I want to do is to pass the variable AND the data to the template.
In my code I have the following:

```
type Username struct {
    Username string
}

type Order struct {
    Order_id int
    Customer string
    Date_of_purchase string
}

func OrderPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    db := dbConnection()
    username := r.URL.Query().Get("username")
    query, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE customer=?", username)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer query.Close()

    order := Order{}
    results := []Order{}
    for query.Next(){
        var order_id int
        var customer, date_of_purchase string
        query.Scan(&order_id, &customer, &date_of_purchase)
        order.Order_id = order_id
        order.Customer = customer
        order.Date_of_purchase = date_of_purchase
        results = append(results, order)
    }
    fmt.Println(results)
    temp.ExecuteTemplate(w, "user.html", results)
}
```

I am not sure how to pass `username := r.URL.Query().Get("username")` so that I could later access it from the template:

```
<body>
    <h2>Hello!</h2>
    <h4>Here's a list of your orders with us:</h4>
    <ul>
        {{ range . }}
        <li><a href="product?order={{ .Order_id }}">{{ .Order_id }}</a></li>
        {{ end }}
    </ul>
</body>
```

I'm still learning this so I'm not even sure how to approach this. Can I do something like that and how would I access the variable and the data in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a value containing the query results and user name to the template:

```
err := temp.ExecuteTemplate(w, "user.html", &struct {
    Orders []Order
    Username string
}{
    results,
    username,
})
if err != nil {
   // handle error
}
```

Use it like this:

```
<body>
    <h2>Hello {{.Username}}!</h2>
    <h4>Here's a list of your orders with us:</h4>
    <ul>
        {{ range .Orders }}
        <li><a href="product?order={{ .Order_id }}">{{ .Order_id }}</a></li>
        {{ end }}
    </ul>
</body>
```